# BatteryStatus API for Chrome extensions not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension for chrome browser that'll display the battery level of the system (and do couple other stuff) with the [BatteryStatusAPI.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API)
At first I'm just trying to display the battery level using simple canvas, but it doesn't seem to work.

**manifest:**

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Battery",
    "description": "This extension shows the battery stats of the current device.",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "battery_full.png",
        "default_title": "Click Here!"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["icon_changer.js"]
    }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var battery;
navigator.getBattery()
    .then(function (b) {
        battery = b;
    }
);

function drawIcon() {
    var clockCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    clockCanvas.height = 19;
    clockCanvas.width = 19;

    var clockContext = clockCanvas.getContext("2d");
    clockContext.textAlign = "center";
    clockContext.textBaseline = "middle";
    clockContext.font = "9px Arial";
    clockContext.fillText(battery.level, 9, 10);

    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
        imageData: clockContext.getImageData(0, 0, 19, 19)
    });
}

drawIcon();
```

What do you think the problem is?

Comment: What's the value of b inside the callback function? Add a `console.log(b);` there. And read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined`. Having read about asynchronous flow, I still don't understand why "getBattery()" doesn't get executed like the rest of the asynchronous code.

Comment: No, I mean inside `function (b) { ... }`.

Comment: My bad. I'm getting a BatteryManager object exactly as I should.

Comment: You can call `drawIcon()` from inside that function and it should work.

Comment: Perfect. But why is that? `bettery` was introduce out of `getBattery()` scope.

Comment: Read the question and answers I linked in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know for [Navigator.getBattery().then(funcRef)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery), `funcRef` is a function to be called when the battery [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) returned by `navigator.getBattery` gets resolved. Due to asynchronicity, when you call `drawIcon`, `getBattery()` may have not been resolved then `funcRef` will not be executed, which means `battery` is undefined.

You should move `drawIcon` function inside `funcRef`.

```
var battery;
navigator.getBattery()
    .then(function (b) {
        battery = b;
        drawIcon();
    }
);

function drawIcon() {
    // Your logic here
}
```